# c++ extract the template arugments of a function pointer

Tags: c++, reflection, function-pointers, introspection, callable

Is there a way to extract/introspect on templated function pointer to get its template argument types and size?

More generally speaking, what kind of Callables/Invocables in C++ are able to be introspected to get the type info of template args and what are the techiniques?

Edit:
What I'm trying to do is to pass a callable object to some other class as a template parameter and carrying all the info this callable has regarding what template parameters it takes. Then I invoke this callable in a more compile-time and functional friendly way.

https://godbolt.org/z/q3f98177Y

```cpp
template<typename T>
T SomeFunc() {return T{};}

constexpr auto some_func_fp = &SomeFunc<int>;
// can we do some introspection to get the types 
// and size of the template arguments of some templated function pointers?
```

Comment: the problem is template parameter does not (necessarily) have anything to do with the implementation. What you want to do with it?

Comment: `some_func_fp` would be type `int(*)()` btw.

Comment: You can't. This is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can get the return type of `some_func_fp` but you can't even tell it's a template never mind what template arguments it was instantiated with

Comment: Note: If you turned this into a functor, you'd be able to get the parameter, given just a function pointer: `template<class T> struct SomeFunc { T operator()() {return T{};} }; template<class T> struct TypeArgumentHelper {}; template<class T> struct TypeArgumentHelper<SomeFunc<T>> { using type = T; }; template<class T> using SomeFunctTemplateParam_t = typename TypeArgumentHelper<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::type; constexpr auto some_func_fp = SomeFunc<int>{}; using ResultingType = SomeFunctTemplateParam_t<decltype(some_func_fp)>;`

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the comment. This is what I want. Is this a way we can do that with regular function?

Comment: @PasserBy Please see edited section for my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in general, the function's type (and the pointer type) has nothing to do with the template parameter. (in your case you can detect the return type though)

---

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
int SomeFunc(){return 0;}

auto fi = &SomeFunc<int>;
auto ff = &SomeFunc<float>;

// fi has same type as ff, int(*)()
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fi),decltype(ff)>);
```

Comment: Please see edited section for my intention.

Comment: @Nkk you should provide example code for your need. And there is still many problem, for one, a callable object (functor) can have overloads of calls operator.

Comment: @Nkk and still, as this answer shows, function's (or functor's) type may has nothing to do with the template parameter.